# Is switch case a loop or a conditional construct?

Tags: c++, c

I was asked this question in an interview.
I replied that it was a conditional construct because

- It executes once, unlike a loop which has the capability to execute multiple times.
- There is no loop control mechanisms, there is only conditional switching based on different cases.

So is my answer right or wrong, is there a better answer?

Also he asked me the reason why `break;` statements work with switch-case since, `break;` only works with loops.
This question I could not answer.

Comment: Of course there is some standards documentation which clarifies this, it's called ISO/IEC 9899:2011, and is the actual standard used for the C programming language (and ISO/IEC 14882:2011 for the C++ programming language).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks , now i can quote the exact iso standard number , to make my point !!

Comment: Well you can still find the [C11 standards draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) quite easily, and both the C and C++ standard documents are quite cheap to buy on ANSI (just bought a copy of the C11 standard yesterday for $30, well worth it IMO).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, What real benefit is there in buying that instead of referencing a free draft? I guess I've never really understood what kinds of differences there are.

Comment: There is barely any difference at all between the C11 draft and the final standard, at least I have found no such difference.

Comment: While the difference between the draft and the final specification is minimal (if there is any at all), the draft is still a draft.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, But evidently good enough to use as a solid reference on SO, which is all I really use it for apart from sometimes looking up something for myself in there to check.

Comment: @CodeCrusader: the `break` thing is a joke. `break` can be used wherever the Standard says it can be used, and it can be used in switches. Whether `switch` is a "conditional" or a "loop" construct does not matter, syntax is just syntax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C++

`switch` is `selection-statement`

n3376 6.4/1 and 6.4.2 is about `switch`

```
selection-statement:
...
switch ( condition ) statement
```

`break` is `jump-statement`

n3376 6.6.1/1

> The break statement shall occur only in an iteration-statement or a switch statement and causes termination
> of the smallest enclosing iteration-statement or switch statement; control passes to the statement following
> the terminated statement, if any.

Comment: In case you're interested, [N3485](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) is there, too.

Comment: @ForEveR, Speaking of new, [N3690](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf) was just released, and contains C++14 information, but I would really heed the big warning at the top.

Answer (score 7):

**C answer**

There is no formal term called "conditional construct". The C standard uses the term *selection statement*. The C language has three different selection statements: `if`, `if-else` and `switch` (C11 6.8.4). Loops sort under the category of *iteration statements* (6.8.5).

The `break` statement is a jump statement, just like `goto`. It has some restrictions of where it is allowed to appear:

> C11 6.8.6.3
>
> A break statement shall appear only in or as a switch body or loop
>   body.

---

So to answer the interview questions:

> Is switch case a loop or a conditional construct?

If you by conditional construct mean a selection statement, then yes, `switch` is a conditional construct.

> why break; statements work with switch-case since, break; only works with loops

No, the question is incorrect, it does not only work with loops. It works with `switch` *and* loops. This is because the C language is defined in that way (6.8.6.3).

Answer (score 0):

A switch case is a way of wrapping a block of instructions and saying execute (part of) it, beginning here and ending here. The matching `case` marks the beginning and the following `break` marks the end.

The block could be a few instructions:

```
{
     instruction_A;
     instruction_B;
     instruction_C;
     instruction_D;
}
```

The `case` statements say where to dynamically start based upon the `switch` value:

```
switch(value)
{
case one:
     instruction_A;
     instruction_B;
case two:
     instruction_C;
case three:
     instruction_D;
}
```

In case `one`, all the instructions will be called, as there is no break. Case `two` will execute C and D, if there are no exceptions (c;.

The `break` statements say where to stop, and mean it's possible to drop through a number of case statements:

```
switch(value)
{
case one:
     instruction_A;
     instruction_B;
case two:
     instruction_C;
     break;
case three:
     instruction_D;
}
```

Case `one` will now execute A, B, and C, but not D.

Comment: While a good summary of what these keywords do, I don't see how this addresses the actual questions asked, which were not about the results of using `switch`, but rather how it should be categorised and why.

Comment: @underscore_d A `switch` statement is neither a conditional nor a loop. It is a way of selecting part of a block of code for execution. This is addressed in the answer. The question also asks why we can use break if it is not a loop, and the answer addresses the role the `break` keyword plays with `switch`.